error: linker `link.exe` not found while using VS code
I keep getting this error when trying to run a basic hello world program in rust and when I tried running it I got an error saying that I need a program called link.exe, how do I install this for VS Code.
I did google it but everything that came up was for regular Visual Studio, not VS code

You need to install the "Visual Studio Build Tools" even when using VS Code. It uses the Visual Studio installer but you do not need to install Visual Studio.
Just follow the instructions under "Manual install" and "Installing only the required components" from the Rustup MSVC prerequisites page.
